# Jersey-Jackson mapping issue for primitive fields in a user-defined class

Tags: java, angularjs, rest, jersey, jackson

I am using AngularJS on client side and Java with jersey + jackson for RESTful webservice on server side.

I am using HTTP PUT method to update a record. I am sending a parameter (JSON object) from the angular client application to the java webservice application.

Our POJO class have some primitive numeric fields (long/int) with default 0 value. But upon receiving JSON containing blank string for those fields, **jersey-jackson maps the value of those numeric fields to null and that is not the intended behavior we want to have**.

How to configure the webservice application to map default values (0 for numeric fields) in cases when empty values are sent from the client application?

**Sample POJO class at the java webservice project:**

```
@XmlRootElement
public class modelclass {
    private Long telephoneNumber = 0;
    private Long faxNumber = 0;
    private String name = "";
public modelclass (String jsonData) {
        ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();
        try {
            modelclass pdo = mapper.readValue(jsonData, modelclass.class);
            this.telephoneNumber = pdo.telephoneNumber;
            this.faxNumber = pdo.faxNumber;
            this.name = pdo.name;
        }
}
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You have a couple of options. You don't mention what versions of Jersey/Jackson you're using so I'll assume 2.x+ for both.

Using your existing code you can check for `null` values before you assign the value to your field.

You could also rewrite your POJO with Jackson annotations:

```
@JsonAutoDetect(fieldVisibility = Visibility.ANY)
@JsonIgnoreProperties(ignoreUnknown = true)
public class ModelClass {
    private Long telephoneNumber = 0;
    private Long faxNumber = 0;
    private String name = "";
}
```

`@JsonAutoDetect` tells Jackson to work with even `private` fields while `@JsonIgnoreProperties` makes it ignore extraneous stuff in the json input string. I haven't tested this but it should do what you want.

On a side note, any particular reason you're using `Long` to store phone numbers? I always store them as `String` or some sort of URI. I find it makes display/formatting much easier.

Comment: First of - we are using jersey 1.8 and jackson 1.9.x.Now the method that gets called for a specific url, if we specify modelClass as one of the parameters to that method, the constructor accepting String argument (json string) does not even get called. We had to change it to "String arg" to receive the json and then call the constructor manually.

Comment: and secondly as I understand you misinterpret the question, the problem is that do we have any automated request interceptor or such sort of functionality in jersey/jackson so that upon detecting blank values in json it would assign/map to java type's default value for primitive types and not null.

Comment: Regardless, you could still check for a null value in your existing constructor. I'm not aware of any interceptor functionality that would do what you're looking for. The only other option would be write custom `MessageBodyReader`/`MessageBodyWriter` implementations for each of your classes...that's a lot of work.

Answer (score 0):

As an option you can add validation of the input values in the constructor, or register a custom Long [deserializer](https://github.com/FasterXML/jackson-docs/wiki/JacksonHowToCustomDeserializers) which sets the default value for a null field.

Here is an example:

```
public class JacksonDefaultValues {
    public static class Model {
        private final long  telephoneNumber;
        private final long faxNumber;
        private final String name;

        @JsonCreator
        public Model(@JsonProperty("telephoneNumber") Long telephoneNumber,
                     @JsonProperty("faxNumber") Long faxNumber,
                     @JsonProperty("name") String name) {
            // add validation as follows:
            // this.telephoneNumber = telephoneNumber == null ? 1234567l : telephoneNumber;
            this.telephoneNumber = telephoneNumber;
            this.faxNumber = faxNumber;
            this.name = name;
        }

        @Override
        public String toString() {
            return "Model{" +
                    "telephoneNumber=" + telephoneNumber +
                    ", faxNumber=" + faxNumber +
                    ", name='" + name + '\'' +
                    '}';
        }
    }

    private static class LongDeserializerDefaultValue extends StdDeserializer<Long> {
        private final long defaultValue;

        protected LongDeserializerDefaultValue(long defaultValue) {
            super(Long.TYPE);
            this.defaultValue = defaultValue;
        }

        @Override
        public Long getNullValue() {
            return defaultValue;
        }

        @Override
        public Long deserialize(JsonParser jp, DeserializationContext ctxt) throws IOException {
            return _parseLong(jp, ctxt);
        }
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
        ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();
        SimpleModule testModule = new SimpleModule()
                .addDeserializer(Long.class, new LongDeserializerDefaultValue(678));
        mapper.registerModule(testModule);
        String json = "{\"telephoneNumber\":0,\"name\":\"John\"}";
        System.out.println(mapper.readValue(json, Model.class));
    }

}
```

Output:

```
Model{telephoneNumber=0, faxNumber=678, name='John'}
```